# Is it possible to encrypt the images of android device using react native?

Tags: react-native

I am developing an app where I take photos using react-native-image-picker and upload those to the AWS server. Once after uploading those I want to encrypt those taken images in the Android device i.e in saved folder. Is it possible to do? If yes, How can I do that using react-native?
My code is,
I am able to capture images and uploading to the AWS s3.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Alert,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Picker,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
import { RNS3 } from "react-native-aws3";

export default class SecondScreen extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: "",
      saveImages: []
    };
  }

  takePic() {
    ImagePicker.launchCamera({}, responce => {
      const file = {
        uri: responce.uri,
        name: responce.fileName,
        method: "POST",
        path: responce.path,
        type: responce.type,
        notification: {
          enabled: true
        }
      };
      this.state.saveImages.push(file);
    });
  }
  _upload = saveImages => {
    const config = {
      keyPrefix: "uploads/",
      bucket: "s3merahkee",
      region: "us-east-2",
      accessKey: "***",
      secretKey: "***",
      successActionStatus: 201
    };

    this.state.saveImages.map(image => {
      RNS3.put(image, config).then(responce => {
        console.log(saveImages);
      });
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.Camera}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePic.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Take Picture</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.Send}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._upload()}>
            <Text>Send</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using two methods here, one the for capturing images and once the user clicks on send it to upload the file to AWS s3.

I hope I can encrypt the image If possible tell me how can I implement it. Or if not possible suggest me the other way that I can do it. (EX: deleting, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using converting image to base64. Using react-native-fs library, I am able to achieve this. Here, Once I captured the images I convert them to a base64 string and delete the real image from the folder.

My code is,

```
takePic = () => {

      // create a path you want to write to
      var pictureFolder = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir+'/Schoolapp';
        ImagePicker.launchCamera(options,(responce)=>{
          const file ={
            uri   : responce.uri,
            name  : responce.fileName,
            method: 'POST',
            path : responce.path,
            type :  responce.type,
            notification: {
                enabled: true
              }
          }

        //convert image into base64  
         const base64 = RNFS.writeFile(responce.uri, responce.data);
         return base64;

        //delete the original image    
         RNFS.unlink(responce.path)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('deleted');
            RNFS.scanFile(responce.path)
              .then(() => {
                console.log('scanned');
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })

        });
    }
```